# Adjust the image offset and image crop for multiple strips

Tags: image, video-sequence-editor

Initially I had done my video in a portrait size 9x16, but now I want to make it wider - something like 16x16.

So I changed the render size, but now all the strips are resized (not proportionally too) to fit the new size. I know that by checking the Image Crop property and adjusting Image Offset I can have the strip stay in the input size.

But I have many strips, is there a way to apply these settings for multiple strips. Is there some plugin or script?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, there is a script called **Extra Sequencer Actions**

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Extra_Sequencer_Actions

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?248129-Extra-Sequencer-Actions

Initially I came across it they were mainly talking about batch editing proxies. But after installation I found it had and many sub menus under the Strip menu.

It behaves as desired.